# Assigning value to the label which is inside gridview from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have call one label inside gridview and want to assign the value for that label from code behind but couldnot being able to do that.I have created rowbound of that gridview like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       Label lbltotal= e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
        String price=Session["price"].ToString();
        DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
       lbltotal.Text = dt.Compute("sum(price)", "").ToString();
    }
```

And I am getting error like this:

> *(Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`e.Row.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `System.Web.UI.Control` and this needs to be cast to the `Label` control explicitly

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   Label lbltotal= e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal") as Label;

   if(lbltotal != null)
   {
     String price=Session["price"].ToString();
     DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
     lbltotal.Text = dt.Compute("sum(price)", "").ToString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an explicit conversion to it

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
       Label lbltotal= e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal") as Label; //explicit convert to label
       if(lbltotal != null)
         {
            String price=Session["price"].ToString();
            DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
           lbltotal.Text = dt.Compute("sum(price)", "").ToString();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the 1st line inside method definition as below:

```
Label lbltotal= e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal") as Label;
```

Comment: You should probably add null checking in there as it could lead to an exception being thrown

Comment: yes, perhaps. I have just tried to approach to his blocking issue, `(Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?))` in this case.

Comment: yes it removes that error but as gridview rowbound function load before binding to gridview I am getting error as object set to reference as null beacuse  I have kept price in session in Bindgrid function.Please suggest me.

Comment: @user3247426 See my solution for null check

Answer (score 0):

you can do as :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {      
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     Label lbltotal=(Label) e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
     String price=Session["price"].ToString();
     DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
     lbltotal.Text = dt.Compute("sum(price)", "").ToString();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a `Label` you need to cast the `Control` returned from `FindControl` to it. You should also check if the row is a `DataControlRowType.DataRow`, otherwise you are also looking for the label in the header and footer.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lbltotal= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbltotal");
        var allRows = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row.Table.AsEnumerable();
        decimal totalPrice = allRows.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Price"));
        lbltotal.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
    }
}
```